# empty match in Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I've made the following regex with case insenstive `\i`

```
(([a-z]+(\s*-\s*[a-z]+)?)\:)\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m)
```

for this kind of input

```
Mon - Fri: 10:00 am - 8:00 pm 
Sat:    10:00 am - 7:00 pm 
Sun: 12:00 am - 5:00 pm
```

but I am getting these matches

```
Match 1
1.  Mon - Fri:
2.  Mon - Fri
3.  - Fri
4.  10:00 am - 8:00 pm
Match 2
1.  Sat:
2.  Sat
3.   
4.  10:00 am - 7:00 pm
Match 3
1.  Sun:
2.  Sun
3.   
4.  12:00 am - 5:00 pm
```

why am I getting the 3rd (empty and "-Fri") matches?

you can play around with this in http://rubular.com/r/M4a1Jnnyrm

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order not to see that, just make the group *non-capturing* (`(?:\s*\-\s*[A-Za-z]+)?`):

```
 (([A-Za-z]+(?:\s*\-\s*[A-Za-z]+)?)\:)\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m)
```

I'd even say that the 2nd group can also be non-capturing:

```
 ((?:[a-z]+(?:\s*-\s*[a-z]+)?)\:)\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m)
```

Now, [it is much cleaner](http://rubular.com/r/89KhWmNuy4), with just 2 groups.

Answer (score 2):

Because in this `Mon - Fri: 10:00 am - 8:00 pm` input, your **optional** third capturing group `(\s*-\s*[a-z]+)?` matches the `- Fri` part. For the others `Sat:    10:00 am - 7:00 pm`, there isn't a second part (*the hyphen part*) of string to capture like in the first string. So the third group returns an empty match for string 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd matches are captured by the group `(\s*-\s*[a-z]+)`

You can use a non-capturing group to omit the 3rd match group e.g.

```
(([a-z]+(?:\s*-\s*[a-z]+)?)\:)\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m\s*-\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[ap]m)
```